# Proving that products of paths respects homotopy rel endpoints

Tags: general-topology

I'd like to show that given paths $f \cong g$ and $f' \cong g'$, homotopic relative their endpoints, then $f \cdot f' \cong g \cdot g'$ assuming of course that the $f$ ends where $f'$ begins, and similarly for $g$ and $g'$.

What I've got so far is a candidate homotopy between $f \cdot f'$ and $g \cdot g'$: If $H$ is the homotopy between $f$ and $g$ and $H'$ is the homotopy between $f'$ and $g'$, then I define the map by the formula $(x,t) \mapsto (H_{t} \cdot H'_{t})(x)$. This map has the desired values at $(x,0), (x,1)$, etc., but I'm not sure how to show this is continuous/if this continuous.

Can anyone help me out? If possible, I was hoping to see if this could be obtained using only universal properties. I've been trying to use the universal property for quotients (and using the canonical projection $I \times I \rightarrow I$ as a quotient map and maybe factoring through), but maybe I'm doing this wrong. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Have you tried using the Glueing Lemma? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma